# bootstrap Input form in modal dropped to bottom after navbar resize to small browsing area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Sorry guys. This is my first time using Stack Overflow to ask question. I really don't know how to leave code on this board but here is my linke.
http://www.bootply.com/Ak03ynsFUE

What I am trying to do is using Bootstrap modal for full screen search, but the whole entire search bar dropped to bottom of modal after I resize the browser to small size. I don't know how to make it stay at the same position as it was in regular browsing size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your custom CSS to overwrite the Bootstrap modal style:

```
#search {
   top: 50%;
   bottom: auto;
   margin-top: -60px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for that idea, when I add it to my code it work, but I also realized that the modal can't be click out. I mean when I click out side of other area, it suppose to make modal disappear, but it doesn't.